# How to have hash for number that does'nt change with permutations?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I need a algorithim to generates a unique hash, not necessirily fixed length, for a integer such that it is independent of permutations of digits.

Like, the hash of 123, 321, 312, 213... should be the same. (Ignore the leading zeroes)

What I tried was to raise every digit to itself and sum up. Like,

```
Hash(321) = 3**3 + 2**2 + 1**1
```

Now, I am not sure whether it will generate collissions or not and there is, certainly, a performance issue for large numbers. Any alternatives?

Comment: A *hash* is not safe against collisions in any way, at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Generate a unique ID for a number such that it is independent of permutations of digits of the number.

Comment: @Shubham: Why not just sort the digits, and use the result as the hash?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Can that be fast enough? Also in languages like C++, sorting digits, wont it require many more steps?

Comment: When you say "many *more*", it sounds like you're comparing "it" to something (*more* is a relative term), what in particular are you comparing to?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Well it is integer. I can't think of any method to sort the digits without putting them to array, sorting them, and rejoining them, atleas in C++. Hence, the 'more steps'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option: Sort the digits. 123, 321, 312, and 213 all go to 123.

Another option: Use a vector of the counts of each digit as the hash. 123, 321, 312, and 213 all go to [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0].

Comment: The second one looks  pretty good. Are you sure that there wont be any collisions in it?

Comment: No, there are none. It's functionally identical to sorting the digits in fact.

Comment: Thats fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need any hash function (let's take md5) and a way to commutatively join things.  Take the hash of each digit and then join them with the commutative method.  For example if I choose md5 and addition then I could md5 each digit and add the resulting hashes.  If I choose to instead use sha1 and multiplication that would give me a different result but it would still have the properties you want.  The questions of collisions is harder...

Comment: Well a MD5 hash is 16 byte long. Certainly If I add up the hashes (assuming you mean join from end to end), that would become really long even for small integers.

Comment: If you want any chance of "uniqueness", it's going to have to be large.

Comment: That would become monstrous not only large.

Comment: I think he means adding the hashes arithmetically. That would work, it's just a pretty silly way of using MD5. (You might as well just choose ten random bit strings instead of MD5(0), MD5(1)...)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a 
cross sum as algorithm